# Where are my passwords stored in browser?

Tags: passwords, browser, storage

When i click the remember me radio while signing into a web application, I know that my password is saved into somewhere inside my browser. I want to know the exact location of that file in my OS directory.

Comment: It depends on your browser and OS. Different browsers implement it differently. One way is to store the password hash within an SQLite database located under the application directory. You may like to take a look at [this article](http://raidersec.blogspot.sg/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html).

Comment: Actually, if you click "remember me" in a web form, odds are it is being stored by the app in a cookie, though it is possible that it is in client storage. If you let the browser itself save it, via the popup/toolbar/whatever, then it depends on the browser mechanism. Either way, this is not a security question...

Comment: Can you please tell us which OS and browser you are using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Firefox browser. I wish to know about chrome also.